# Missing required parameters for [Route: assortments.items.create] [URI: assortments/{assortment}/items/create]

Tags: laravel

So in Laravel I have written a test, in this test I wanna see if a page returns status 200.
The test goes as follows:

```
public function testUserCanSeeItems()
    {
        $this->signIn();
        $this->get(route('assortments.items'))->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

I used `assortments.items` since that is also the route I defined in my `web.php`:

```
Route::resource('assortments.items', ItemController::class)
        ->only(['create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy']);
```

Now when I run the test I get the following error:
`Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [assortments.items] not defined.`

So I decided should put `.create` behind it to see if it will make it work:

```
public function testUserCanSeeItems()
    {
        $this->signIn();
        $this->get(route('assortments.items.create'))->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Now I get the following error and I do not know how to solve this:
`Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException: Missing required parameters for [Route: assortments.items.create] [URI: assortments/{assortment}/items/create].`

I just wanna know what the right route is that I should insert.

Comment: You can try `php artisan route:list` and find out the correct route name.

Comment: Yh, that gives me `assortments.items.create` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource is sub resource routing. So everything related to `items` needs a `assortment` id as well.

If this is done on purpose then you are just missing the `assortment` parameter:

```
route('assortments.items.create', ['assortment' => ...])
```

You need to pass some value for `assortment` since there is a required route parameter.

Again, you did not define a route `assortments.items` you defined a nested resource named `items` that is a sub resource of `assortments`.

Comment: But that is not how I have written my route. Do you mean I should add the `assortment` parameter in my `web.php` or in my test? And what is that value I should pass for an `assortment`?

Comment: this is exactly how you wrote your route ... you are creating  a "sub resource" ... that is what the `.` in the resource name is for, it signifies it is a "nested resource"  ... please look at `php artisan route:list` to see how `Route::resource` registers your routes

Comment: Yeah I already took a look at `php artisan route:list` and it registers it as: `assortment.items.create`

Comment: correct, which is how it should be ... so what is the problem? if you notice the route URIs for all of the ones named `assortments.items.*` will have a required route parameter `{assortment}`

Comment: The problem is that when I do put `assortment.items.create` in my test to see if that page returns a 200 status it tells me I am missing the required parameters. Now your telling me I should add a `assortment` parameter and give it a value. My question: do I have to add it in my test or `web.php`, and what value do I have to pass in it.

Comment: no the route is already defined .... as you can see the route URI takes a parameter ... that is why you need to pass one to the route helper ... your route is already defined, just use it and pass the required parameter to it when calling the `route` helper

Comment: What is the route helper? You mean the `only([])` I made?

Comment: the function named `route` that you are calling to generate URLs, the `route` helper function

Comment: Oke, so I have to pass a parameter in the `route` function in my testfile. But what value do I have to pass in it?

Comment: what ever Assortment the Item is related to ... again you have not defined a set of resource routes, you defined a NESTED resource ... Item is dependent upon Assortment

Comment: Yeah but that could be any assortment, there are tens of them

Comment: then pick one  ... it is required to pass something for the `assortment` route parameter

Comment: Yeah I can just pick one and make my tests based on that one. Thats fine as well. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Btw, I should pass the`name` or `id` of that one assortment?

Comment: considering you are not actually using it, what ever you want